# Set Property in App.xaml.cs using async-method

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-8.1

I want to have a property in my App.xaml.cs which look like:

```
private static Settings _settings = null;
public static Settings AppSettings
{
   get
   {
      if(_settings == null)
         _settings = await Settings.Deserialize();

      return _settings;
   }
}
```

In the Settings.Deserialize() I am reading setting from file so it have next signature:

```
public static async Task<Settings> Deserialize() { ... }
```

I can not use await in the property.  But what is the good solution in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make getter and setter functions instead of a property. You shouldn't use properties for things that have side effects in the first place (no saving to or from storage/db/web service, etc.)